# Recibir datos de un checkbox en PHP

Tags: php, html

Es posible capturar un dato de tabla de MySQL en un formulario con un checkbox como si fuera booleano, es decir necesito capturar lo siguiente:

```
Nombre de empleado
Tiene Deuda   Si _ No _
```

Pero esta parte no encuentro cómo pasarla a la parte de inserción de datos en la base de datos.

Éste es el código que tengo en HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Prestamos" id="Prestamos" value="1">
```

Con éste ya lo recibo:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['Prestamos']) && $_POST['Prestamos'] == '1')
      echo '<div style="color:green">El empleado tiene deudas</div>';
   else
      echo '<div style="color:red">El empleado no tiene deudas.</div>';

?>
```

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro cuál era el problema o qué error recibías, pero me alegro que alguien te diera la respuesta

Comment: basicamente no recordaba y no encontraba como introducir datos desde un checkbox a una base de datos pero por suerte ya quedo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si se puede.
Voy a suponer que tienes un *index.html* donde tienes el formulario y lo vas a mandar a *guardarDeuda.php* (no se como los hayas llamado tu) y que estas utilizando myslqi.

Intenta algo asi

```
<h1>Tiene deuda</h1>
<form method="guardarDeuda.php" action="post">
<label for="primerOpcion">Si</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Prestamos" id="primerOpcion">
<label for="segundaOpcion">No</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="0" name="Prestamos" id="segundaOpcion">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" />
</form>
```

en el archivo *guardarDeuda.php* ..

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
   if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
$deudas =$_POST['Prestamos'];
if($deudas){
echo "TIENE DEUDAS";
}else{
echo "NO TIENE DEUDAS";
}
$conexion->query("INSERT INTO deudores (deudas) values('$deudas')");
}
header("Location:index.html");
      exit();
     ?>
```

archivo *conexion.php*

```
<?php
$s = "localhost";
$bd = ""; // nombre de base de datos
$u = "root"; //usuario
$p = ""; //contraseña

$conexion = new mysqli($s, $u, $p, $bd);
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "no conectado";
}


?>
```

Ya solo tendrias que guardar la variable $deudas en tu base de datos, recuerda que 1 lo guarda como true y false == 0.
Espero te sirva. saludos

Comment: gracias @Juan Daniel  entonces podria utilizarlo asi para la parte del guardado   <br/>  `<?php




if(!empty($_POST)){
 if(isset($_POST["prestamos"])){
  if($_POST["prestamos"]!=""&& ){
   include "conexion.php";
   
   $sql = "insert into deudores(deudas,fecha) value (\"$_POST[prestamos]\",NOW())";
   $query = $con->query($sql);
   if($query!=null){
    print "<script>alert(\"Agregado exitosamente.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";
   }else{
    print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo agregar.\");window.location='../ver.php';</script>";

   }
  }
 }
}



?>`

Comment: @franksegovia edite la respuesta, no lo probe pero puedes intentar algo asi.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no entendi muy bien la pregunta, te refieres al lado de sql?

Dependiendo de que servidor de Mysql estes utilizando 
Puedes usar el datatype `BIT` en tu insert.
Asi ya utilizas valores como `0` y `1` para tu boolean.

Tambien puedes usar el Datatype `TINYINT()`

Donde `TINYINT(0)` es equivalente a `FALSE`
y `TINYINT(1)` es equivalente a `TRUE`

True y False de `TINYINT()` es exactamente el equivalente en `BIT` son solo `0` y `1`

```
mysql> SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(0, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| false                  |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(1, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(2, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+
```

Te dejo como fuente la documentacion de MySQL [Documentacion de DataTypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)